# splitting a word in a string into each letter

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader, wordle-game

So i am basically trying to make wordle in java(if you don't know what it is look it up its a fun word game), and I have a text file of a bunch of words. I randomly pick 1 of the words using a bufferd reader which would be the word you have to guess, I don't know how you would be able to check each letter after you guess a word. I think I need to split the string up into individual letters so I tried doing this   `line.toCharArray()` line being the string name, but that didn't work. here is the code from where i read the line

```
int min = 1;
    int max = 101;
    Random r = new Random();
    int value = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
    
    
    int lines = 0;
    File text = new File("text.txt");
     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text)))
    {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines++;
                if(lines == value)
                    line.toCharArray()
                    System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you can do something like `char[] array = string.toCharArray()`, but you can also access each character position directly using `string.charAt(position)` (in place of `array[position]` with first solution)

Comment: Just use str.charAt(index) to get character by character the word?

Comment: What do you mean "that didn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
for( int codePoint : line.codePoints().toArray() ) { … }
```

## Avoid `char`

As a 16-bit value, `char` type is physically incapable of representing most characters. The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5.

## Code points

Instead use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. A code point is the number permanently assigned to each character by the Unicode Consortium.

Here is code to get the code points of some text as an array. This code generates an `IntStream` to access each character’s code point. Then we collect the elements of that stream into an array of `int` primitive numbers.

```
int[] codePoints = line.codePoints().toArray() ;
```

Now you can loop those code point numbers.

```
for( int codePoint : codePoints ) 
{
    …
}
```

You can generate text from the code point numbers in various ways.

Here’s one, using `Character.toString`.

```
String s = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

And another is calling `StringBuilder#appendCodePoint`.

---

By the way, the `ThreadLocalRandom` class has more convenient methods than `Random`.

This:

```
int min = 1;
int max = 101;
Random r = new Random();
int value = r.nextInt(max-min) + min;
```

… becomes this, without any math needed.

```
int origin = 1, bound = 101;
int value = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( origin, bound );
```

Tip: Work on better naming of your variables than “value”.

---

Comment: This is good advice in general but a bit overkill for a Wordle game that is almost certainly not going to use any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @DavidConrad How much extra work is it to handle code points rather than `char`, really? And why knowingly write code that may break with one stray emoji? Why develop two sets of skills, `char` sometimes and code points other times, rather than just using code points all the time? What exactly does one gain by using `char`?

Answer (score 0):

`String.toCharArray()` method returns `char[]` and won't modify the original string

```
char[] letters = line.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

Reference: [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)